# Julia DataFrames: Problems with Split-Apply-Combine strategy

Tags: julia

I have some data (from a R course assignment, but that doesn't matter) that I want to use split-apply-combine strategy, but I'm having some problems. The data is on a DataFrame, called outcome, and each line represents a Hospital. Each column has an information about that hospital, like name, location, rates, etc.

**My objective is to obtain the Hospital with the lowest "Mortality by Heart Attack Rate" of each State.**

I was playing around with some strategies, and got a problem using the `by` function:

```
best_heart_rate(df) = sort(df, cols = :Mortality)[end,:]
best_hospitals = by(hospitals, :State, best_heart_rate)
```

The idea was to split the `hospitals` DataFrame by State, sort each of the SubDataFrames by Mortality Rate, get the lowest one, and combine the lines in a new DataFrame

But when I used this strategy, I got:

```
ERROR: no method nrow(SubDataFrame{Array{Int64,1}})
 in sort at /home/paulo/.julia/v0.3/DataFrames/src/dataframe/sort.jl:311
 in sort at /home/paulo/.julia/v0.3/DataFrames/src/dataframe/sort.jl:296
 in f at none:1
 in based_on at /home/paulo/.julia/v0.3/DataFrames/src/groupeddataframe/grouping.jl:144
 in by at /home/paulo/.julia/v0.3/DataFrames/src/groupeddataframe/grouping.jl:202
```

I suppose the `nrow` function is not implemented for SubDataFrames, so I got an error. So I used a nastier code:

```
best_heart_rate(df) = (df[sortperm(df[:,:Mortality] , rev=true), :])[1,:]
best_hospitals = by(hospitals, :State, best_heart_rate)
```

Seems to work. But now there is a `NA` problem: how can I remove the rows from the SubDataFrames that have `NA` on the `Mortality` column? Is there a better strategy to accomplish my objective?

Answer (score 3):

I think this might work, if I've understood you correctly:

```
# Let me make up some data about hospitals in states
hospitals = DataFrame(State=sample(["CA", "MA", "PA"], 10), mortality=rand(10), hospital=split("abcdefghij", ""))
hospitals[3, :mortality] = NA

# You can use the indmax function to find the index of the maximum element
by(hospitals[complete_cases(hospitals), :], :State, df -> df[indmax(df[:mortality]), [:mortality, :hospital]])



    State   mortality             hospital
1   CA      0.9469632421111882    j
2   MA      0.7137144590022733    f
3   PA      0.8811901895164764    e
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want, but my DataFrame has `NA`s on `mortality` row. The function `indmax()` isn't implemented for DataFrames yet, so I still get an error.

Comment: You can use `complete_cases` to select only the complete rows of the dataframe. I've edited the response. There should really be a `dropna` for dataframes.