# How to "join" with the split-apply-combine method in Julia

Tags: datatable, julia, split-apply-combine

I have a somewhat complex join (in the SQL sense) that I would like to perform in Julia, but I can't figure out how to get it working in the split-apply-combine method (although it can be written out by hand).  It seems like this should be easy to do though.  The problem looks something like this.  I have a DataFrame of data on turtles running races:

```
using DataFrames
data = DataFrame()
data[:turtle] = ["Suzy", "Suzy", "Bob", "Batman", "Batman", "Batman", "Bob"]
data[:event] = ["5k", "5k", "1k", "5k", "5k", "1k", "1k"]
data[:time] = [6.2 , 6.7 , 2.1, 3.2, 3.1, 0.9, 2.4]
data[:photo] =["111.jpg","123.jpg","145.jpg","167.jpg","189.jpg","190.jpg","195.jpg"]
data
```

I would like a datatable which consists of only the rows of this table which are each turtle's personal (turtlenal?) best in any event they ran.  I can get almost what I need with

```
bestFinishes = by(data, [:turtle, :event]) do df
     DataFrame(fastestTime = minimum(df[:time]))
end
```

but I also need the photo column for the matching rows. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as soon as I typed this in I realized one way to do it based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806758/julia-dataframes-problems-with-split-apply-combine-strategy).

```
bestFinishes = by(data, [:turtle, :event]) do df
    DataFrame(fastestTime = minimum(df[:time]), winningPhoto = df[indmin(df[:time]),:photo] )
end
```

However, a more general way to do this is

```
bestFinishes = by(data, [:turtle, :event]) do df
    thisFastestTime = minimum(df[:time])
    df[df[:time].==thisFastestTime,:]
end
```

Which makes things easier if you just want to prune rows from a very large data set efficiently.  I'll see if I can add an example like this to the documentation since it didn't seem like it was covered (or just assumed more familiarity with this method than I had).